# splitting a data field into two based on a charatcer count

Tags: sed, awk

My problem is:

I have data that looks like this:

```
>header_GH_X
12 15 53 43 23 25 45 56 4544 32 3 42 53
>header2
15 34 155 6 54 7 66 8888 23 12 23 45
```

But it should look like this:

```
>header_GH_Y
12 15 53 43 23 25 45 56 45 44 32 3 42 53
>header2
15 34 15 5 6 54 7 66 88 88 23 12 23 45
```

Every second line consists of fields with numbers that can only be either one or two digits. Has anyone a simple awk solution to go to every second line and, count the characters in each field, and when there is more than 2 characters, split the field into two e.g. 245 becomes 24 5 and 2345 becomes 23 45

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a sed one-liner could do it

```
sed -r 's/([0-9]{2})([0-9]+)/\1 \2/g'
```

test

```
kent$  echo ">header_GH_X
12 15 53 43 23 25 45 56 4544 32 3 42 53
>header2
15 34 155 6 54 7 66 8888 23 12 23 45"|sed -r 's/([0-9]{2})([0-9]+)/\1 \2/g'
>header_GH_X
12 15 53 43 23 25 45 56 45 44 32 3 42 53
>header2
15 34 15 5 6 54 7 66 88 88 23 12 23 45
```

Comment: This did the job perfectly. Thank You.

Comment: @user1308144 are you sure? Could your input contain numbers with more than 4 digits and could the number of headers reach over 100?

Comment: @sudo_O In this case it will never be more than 4 digits. The header will also not cause a problem in this case (follows the style of first header in example) , but thanks for pointing it out as it would cause a problem in the case of sequentially numbered headers.

Answer (score 4):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/^>/!s/\S\S\B/& /g' file
```

For all lines that don't begin with a `>` add a space after 2 non-spaces inside a word.

Answer (score 2):

[**@Kent**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18270157/1066031) was almost there but his solutions fails in two case. If the header ID is greater then 2 digits it will be split and for digits greater then 4 won't be split in groups of 2. For instance take the following as the input file:

```
$ cat file
>header_GH_X
12 15 53 43 23 25 45 56 4544 32 3 42 53
>header2
15 34 155 6 54 7 66 8888 23 12 23 45
>header102
15 34 155 6 54 7 66 88888888 23 12 23 45
```

With some small changes this is easily fixed:

```
$ sed -r ':a;2~2s/([0-9]{2})([0-9]+)/\1 \2/g;ta' file
>header_GH_X
12 15 53 43 23 25 45 56 45 44 32 3 42 53
>header2
15 34 15 5 6 54 7 66 88 88 23 12 23 45
>header102
15 34 15 5 6 54 7 66 88 88 88 88 23 12 23 45
```

Answer (score 2):

And here is an awk solution, (since the question is tagged awk):

```
awk '!/^>/{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) do {printf "%s ", substr($i,0,2); $i=substr($i,3)} while ($i != ""); print "" }/^>/' file
```

or in a more readable format:

```
awk '
    !/^>/{
        for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) 
            do {
                printf "%s ", substr($i,0,2); 
                $i=substr($i,3)
            } while ($i != ""); 
        print "" 
    }
    /^>/
' file
```

Answer (score 0):

awk

```
awk '/^[0-9]/ {gsub(/[0-9][0-9]/,"& ");$1=$1}1' file
>header_GH_X
12 15 53 43 23 25 45 56 45 44 32 3 42 53
>header2
15 34 15 5 6 54 7 66 88 88 23 12 23 45
```